# Type not defined error on calling Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have a web service whose reference i'm giving in my web site. The code in website where i'm defining my web service is below:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class APIUtilities
    Private GD As GetDatFromMDB
    Private _OfflineAPITest As Boolean = False
    Private WSLK As com.teleasy.app1.WBLookup

End Class
```

I get error on this line: `Private WSLK As com.teleasy.app1.WBLookup`

Error message is this:

[image]

Please help. Answers in C# will also help.

Comment: You don't need `c#` tag for this. `vb.net` tag is enough.

Comment: @SonerGönül Answers in C# will also help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to refer to the web service directly, using it's namespace. Don't do that; add a service reference to it instead (right click `References` in VS, click `Add Service Reference`, and enter the URL of the service.

When you add a service reference, the framework will generate classes for you that match the interface of the service, etc. These are the classes you want to use.

You can see info about the service and available methods by right clicking the reference (should now be visible under Service References), and selecting `View in object browser`.

The class you want to call to communicate with the service should be called something like `NameOfTheServiceClient` (i.e. your service-name with *Client* appended).

Comment: Tkx... this helped me. In "Add ServiceReference" - Remember to click 'Advanced' and click '"Aff WebService Reference" and place the URL there NOT in the Service Reference.